# What is a programming language with dynamic scope and static typing?

Tags: dynamic, programming-languages, static, scope

I know the language exists, but I can't put my finger on it.

dynamic scope 
      and 
 static typing?

Comment: Doesn't Fortran have dynamic scoping? At least the older pre-1977 versions?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes. Actually F77 has shared memory areas which are just areas of memory that you can view as containing whatever types you like.

Comment: It seems to me that you can’t implement (type-safe) dynamic scope without runtime type tagging of values, which is dynamic typing in essence. That’s just my first impression, though.

Comment: @JonPurdy That's not true, but it does mean that you need e.g. to carry the type information with the variable (as with fortran's naming rules), or re-declare your use first, and either trust programmers to declare correctly (as in C, where memory holds whatever the programmer says it does, as far as the compiler is concerned), or constrain each (dynamic) name to always have the same type in the programme.

Comment: Adel, it might help to tell us why you thought of this question.

Comment: @Marcin: But “carrying the type information with the variable” is just a crippled means of getting runtime type information. Constraining every use of a dynamically scoped name to have a common type is possible but awful—try it across module boundaries. Dynamic scope means you’re doing name lookup at runtime, and in order to perform type checking, type information has to be there. You can put it in the name if you want, but it’d be an unpopular choice. And “trusting programmers” is *definitely* not safe. ;)

Comment: @JonPurdy No, carrying type information with the variable in the style of Fortran most definitely is not a way of getting runtime type information. It is a way of avoiding variables with the same name having a different static type. Global scope also involves "name lookup at runtime" in the exact same sense, and again, dynamic type checking is not necessary. You seem to be confused about what type safety is, or perhaps where it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

We can try to reason about what such a language might look like. Obviously something like this (using a C-like syntax for demonstration purposes) cannot be allowed, or at least not with the obvious meaning:

```
int x_plus_(int y) {
    return x + y;        // requires that x have type int
}

int three_plus_(int y) {
    double x = 3.0;
    return x_plus_(y);   // calls x_plus_ when x has type double
}
```

So, how to avoid this?

I can think of a few approaches offhand:

1. Commenters above mention that Fortran pre-'77 had this behavior. That worked because a variable's name determined its type; a function like `x_plus_` above would be illegal, because `x` could never have an integer type. (And likewise one like `three_plus_`, for that matter, because `y` would have the same restriction.) Integer variables had to have names beginning with `i`, `j`, `k`, `l`, `m`, or `n`.
2. Perl uses syntax to distinguish a few broad categories of variables, namely scalars vs. arrays (regular arrays) vs. hashes (associative arrays). Variables belonging to the different categories can have the exact same name, because the syntax distinguishes which one is meant. For example, the expression `foo $foo, $foo[0], $foo{'foo'}` involves the function `foo`, the scalar `$foo`, the array `@foo` (`$foo[0]` being the first element of `@foo`), and the hash `%foo` (`$foo{'foo'}` being the value in `%foo` corresponding to the key `'foo'`). Now, to be quite clear, Perl is *not* statically typed, because there are many different scalar types, and these are types *not* distinguished syntactically. (In particular: all references are scalars, even references to functions or arrays or hashes. So if you use the syntax to dereference a reference to an array, Perl has to check at runtime to see if the value really is an array-reference.) But this same approach *could* be used for a *bona fide* type system, especially if the type system were a very simple one. With that approach, the `x_plus_` method would be using an `x` of type `int`, and would completely ignore the `x` declared by `three_plus_`. (Instead, it would use an `x` of type `int` that had to be provided from whatever scope called `three_plus_`.) This could either require some type annotations not included above, or it could use some form of type inference.
3. A function's signature could indicate the non-local variables it uses, and their expected types. In the above example, `x_plus_` would have the signature "takes one argument of type `int`; uses a calling-scope `x` of type `int`; returns a value of type `int`". Then, just like how a function that calls `x_plus_` would have to pass in an argument of type `int`, it would also have to provide a variable named `x` of type `int` — either by declaring it itself, or by inheriting that part of the type-signature (since calling `x_plus_` is equivalent to using an `x` of type `int`) and propagating this requirement up to *its* callers. With this approach, the `three_plus_` function above would be illegal, because it would violate the signature of the `x_plus_` method it invokes — just the same as if it tried to pass a `double` as its argument.
4. The above could just have "undefined behavior"; the compiler wouldn't have to explicitly detect and reject it, but the spec wouldn't impose any particular requirements on how it had to handle it. It would be the responsibility of programmers to ensure that they never invoke a function with incorrectly-typed non-local variables.

Your professor was presumably thinking of #1, since pre-'77 Fortran was an actual real-world language with this property. But the other approaches are interesting to think about. :-)

Comment: Approach 3 is essentially a pass-by-reference or pass-by-name calling discipline.

Comment: @Marcin: Sorry, I don't see the similarity. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Approach 3 defines the variables that the function must have in its scope, and those variables are stored in another stack frame (or, presumably, globally). That's the exact definition of those calling disciplines (which differ primarily in their implementation).

Comment: @Marcin: Ah. I think I see what you're saying, but I disagree. Pass-by-reference and pass-by-name have to do with how arguments are passed, whereas dynamic scoping has to do with name-lookup for non-arguments. Since approach #3 requires the compiler to track all non-arguments that can be looked up within a given function call, it could be "translated" into a pass-by-X model where those non-arguments are converted into explicit arguments; but that's an implementation detail. A language that offers pass-by-reference or pass-by-name cannot really be said to offer dynamic local scope thereby.

Comment: What's the difference between an argument, and a variable mentioned in the function's signature which is required for the function to be called?

Comment: @Marcin: The call syntax. Suppose that the `println` function requires the variable `LINE_SEPARATOR`. Writing `println("foo")` everywhere, with just a single line of code in your entry-point that sets `LINE_SEPARATOR`, is different from having to write `println("foo", LINE_SEPARATOR)` everywhere. (Though if the language supports overloading, and the library is well designed, then `println("foo")` and `println("foo", "\n")` would probably both be available, with the former delegating to the latter.)

Comment: I think you've demonstrated yourself why this difference is not material.

Comment: @Marcin: Eh? Well then, I appear not to have been present for my demonstration. ;-) Care to re-demonstrate it in your own words? To me it still seems like an enormous difference.

Comment: The syntax represents no difference at all. The way you write the function is identical; all that differs is how you invoke the function.

Comment: @Marcin: Re: "The way you write the function is identical": I'm not sure what you mean. In the case of `println`, instead of declaring a `lineSeparator` parameter, the function-body would have some sort of `extern string LINE_SEPARATOR;` declaration; and in the case of all the other intermediate functions that invoke `println`, directly or indirectly, but never mess with the line-separator, the difference is that instead of declaring a `lineSeparator` parameter, they *don't*.

Comment: @Marcin: Actually, wait a sec, I think I see. This aspect of the function signature would actually have to be explicitly recorded in the function header (or whatnot) -- `void println(string s) requires (string LINE_SEPARATOR) { ... }` -- because otherwise, if `main` failed to provide `LINE_SEPARATOR`, the compiler would have no way of knowing which level of the call hierarchy was supposed to have provided it. So yeah, it comes out being pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found elsewhere has it written down, but [AXIOM CAS](http://axiom-developer.org) (and various forks, including [FriCAS](http://fricas-wiki.math.uni.wroc.pl/FrontPage) which is still been actively developed) uses a script language called SPAD with both a very novel strong static dependent type system and dynamic scoping (although it is possibly an unintended implementation bug).

Most of the time the user won't realize that, but when they start trying to build closures like other functional languages it reveals its dynamic scoping nature:

```
                       FriCAS Computer Algebra System 
                         Version: FriCAS 2021-03-06
                   Timestamp: Mon May 17 10:43:08 CST 2021
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Issue )copyright to view copyright notices.
   Issue )summary for a summary of useful system commands.
   Issue )quit to leave FriCAS and return to shell.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 

(1) -> foo (x,y) == x + y
                                                                   Type: Void
(2) -> foo (1,2)
   Compiling function foo with type (PositiveInteger, PositiveInteger)
       -> PositiveInteger 

   (2)  3
                                                        Type: PositiveInteger
(3) -> foo             

   (3)  foo (x, y) == x + y
                                                    Type: FunctionCalled(foo)
(4) -> bar x y == x + y
                                                                   Type: Void
(5) -> bar  

   (5)  bar x == y +-> x + y
                                                    Type: FunctionCalled(bar)
(6) -> (bar 1)
   Compiling function bar with type PositiveInteger -> 
      AnonymousFunction 

   (6)  y +-> #1 + y
                                                      Type: AnonymousFunction
(7) -> ((bar 1) 2)

   (7)  #1 + 2
                                                    Type: Polynomial(Integer)
```

Such a behavior is similar to what will happen when trying to build a closure by using `(lambda (x) (lambda (y) (+ x y)))` in a dynamically scoped Lisp, such as Emacs Lisp. Actually the underlying representation of functions is essentially the same as Lisp in the early days since AXIOM has been first developed on top of an early Lisp implementation on IBM mainframe.

I believe it is however a defect (like what JMC happened did when implementing the first version of LISP language) because the implementor made the parser to do uncurrying as in the function definition of `bar`, but it is unlikely to be useful without the ability to build the closure in the language.

It is also worth notice that SPAD automatically renames the variables in anomalous functions to avoid captures so its dynamic scoping could be used as a feature as in other Lisps.

Answer (score 0):

*Dynamic scope* means, that the variable and its type in a specific line of your code depends on the functions, called before. This means, **you can not know** the type in a specific line of your code, because you can not know, which code has been executed before.

*Static typing* means, that **you have to know** the type in every line of your code, before the code starts to run.

This is irreconcilable.